# Graphics card power consumption regarding PCI power and 6-Pin power

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, pci-express, molex

I am aware that the PCI-E slot can power up to 75W and so can the 6 pin molex power cable, I was wondering if the power draw is split evenly between both the PCI and 6 pin cable, for example would a graphics card using 110W split the consumption evenly into 55W from the PCI and 55W from the 6 pin, or would it be for example 75W from PCI and 35W from the 6 pin?

I ask because my 250W psu will not be enough to power my gtx 650ti and plan on using a secondary psu for the 6 pin connector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this very interesting question. What I know is 250W is barely enough for the most basic system that can use such graphics card not including the card itself. Also doing what you intend to do with 2 PSUs seems to be a very bad idea.

Comment: Ground loops and power imbalances can be dangerous and send power supplies and components to an early grave. Switch mode power supplies need to be specifically designed to synchronise their switching frequencies and have common ground planes so that they  do not cause damage. Doing this is not really a great idea. Get the power supply you need.